# Unable to locate the elements in SmartGWT application using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gwt, smartgwt

I'm a beginner in Selenium and GWT and I am trying to test a GWT web application like Paint in which the SmartGWT library is added. I was encountering a problem trying to locate the elements of the webpage with a single method which will be compatible with all the browsers. I tried many methods for locating the elements but none of them has worked. Firstly, I tried locating the elements using ID which didn't work. Then, I tried the method of absolute XPath which was not working for a few elements on different browsers. Then, I tried locating those elements using relative XPath but unfortunately, the same problem occurred with that method also. Then, I found another way to locate those elements using scLocators as given in this link: [Using Selenium in SmartGWT](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/UsingSelenium.html).

I was able to generate the scLocators in Selenium IDE using the steps mentioned in this link. But when I played the entire test case in the Selenium IDE after stopping the recording, then the IDE itself was not able to find those elements, which it had generated when I was performing various operations like clicking, writing a text, etc.

Moreover, I also used the scLocators to find those elements using the Selenium WebDriver in Java. But again, it didn't work and showed NO SUCH ELEMENT exception.

This is my code.

```
public class RelativeXpath {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\SELENIUM\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    SmartClientWebDriver driver = new SmartClientChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.get("xxxxxx"); //here I have given the URL of my web application
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("XXXX")); // here I've given the title of my web application
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("frontCanvas")));
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    WebElement Draw = driver.findElement(ByScLocator.scLocator("//HLayout[ID=\"long_ribbon_HLayout\"]/member[Class=IconMenuButton||index=1||length=20||classIndex=0||classLength=4||roleIndex=0||roleLength=15||scRole=button]/icon"));
    Draw.click();                                                 
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

}
```

Given below is the HTML code of the image+button element which I want to click.

```
<div id="isc_C" eventproxy="isc_IconButton_Client_0" role="button" aria-label="XXXX" style="position: absolute; left: 80px; top: 0px; width: 42px; height: 42px; z-index: 200090; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;" onscroll="return isc_IconButton_Client_0.$lh()">
   <div id="isc_D" eventproxy="isc_IconButton_Client_0" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; visibility: inherit; z-index: 200090; cursor: pointer;">
     <table role="presentation" width="42" height="42" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="iconButton" style="padding: 4px; background-color: transparent;" valign="top" nowrap="true" align="center">
              <img src="XXXX.png" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:5px;" eventpart="icon" suppress="TRUE" draggable="true" width="32" height="32" border="0" align="TEXTTOP">
                <br>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the HTML layout? Post the html code to your question

Comment: Sorry I can't post the HTML code here because of the rules of my company. But I can give you some relevant information regarding that layout, which you can ask.

Comment: are HTML having svg tags?

Comment: Show me just the HTML for the element you are interested in. And that too the main tag and nothing inside

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I have edited the post and added the HTML code for the element which I want to locate. Actually I want to click on the image element which is located on the top bar in the form of button as you can see in the image.

Comment: @ShubhamJain, No, it has no svg tags.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you below code is wrong

```
WebElement Draw = driver.findElement(ByScLocator.scLocator("//HLayout[ID=\"long_ribbon_HLayout\"]/member[Class=IconMenuButton||index=1||length=20||classIndex=0||classLength=4||roleIndex=0||roleLength=15||scRole=button]/icon"));
```

You need to replace `ByScLocator.scLocator` to `xpath` or `cssSelector` like below

```
WebElement Draw = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//HLayout[ID=\"long_ribbon_HLayout\"]/member[Class=IconMenuButton||index=1||length=20||classIndex=0||classLength=4||roleIndex=0||roleLength=15||scRole=button]/icon"));
```

Now the Xpath you have wrote and the HTML you have shared is totally different.

As per your HTML and if you want to click on element as below

```
<td class="iconButton" style="padding: 4px; background-color: transparent;" valign="top" nowrap="true" align="center">
```

Then use xpath as

```
//td[@class='iconButton']
```

OR

```
//td[@class='iconButton' and @valign='top']
```

Now if your element is below :-

```
<img src="XXXX.png" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:5px;" eventpart="icon" suppress="TRUE" draggable="true" width="32" height="32" border="0" align="TEXTTOP">
```

Then you can use :-

```
(//td[@class='iconButton']/img[@eventpart='icon'])[3]
```

Comment: I tried replacing the ByScLocator.scLocator to xpath as you did but it is again showing the same error. Along with that, if I will use the XPath as you suggested "//td[@class='iconButton']/img[@eventpart='icon']" then as per my knowledge, it will click on the first image icon with these properties but my icon is 3rd or 4th in the list.

Comment: updated my xpath as per the position you have said. Currently it is set for 3rd place you can change it as per your conviences

Comment: Your method works well on Chrome, Firefox and Edge but it is not working on Internet Explorer. What to do? I've posted the this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094310/unable-to-locate-the-elements-of-smartgwt-application-using-selenium-in-ie-brows