# Unable to locate the elements of SmartGWT application using Selenium in IE browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, xpath, selenium-webdriver, gwt

I'm testing a GWT + SMARTGWT application like Paint and I'm trying to locate the elements of this web application using Selenium Webdriver. The method which I have used to locate the elements is by the relative XPath of those elements but the problem which I am currently facing is that this method is working correctly on the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but not on the IE browser. The version of IE on my PC is **11.1593.14393.0**. In the IE browser, this relative XPath method is giving a TimeOutException. I have given the explicit wait:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webelement));`

The IE browser is not able to find the element. I am also getting the following exception sometimes for other elements:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //img[contains(@src,'Insert XXX'] because of the following error:
Error: Bad token: ]
```

Among the troubleshooting solutions to this issue, I tried enabling/disabling the protected mode in IE for all the levels but this method didn't work. Along with that, I also tried checking the box next to the option - "**Allow active content to run files on My Computer**" but this method also failed to work.

What should I do to fix my issue?

This is my code. Here firstly, I will click on the Insert button located on the top bar of the application and after clicking on the Insert button, a window will launch on which I will click on the Close button.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\SELENIUM\\Drivers\\iedriverserver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.get(baseURL);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        final String InsertPath = "//img[contains(@src,'Insert XXXX')]";
        final String closePath="//img[contains(@src,'close')]";
        WebElement Insert = driver.findElement(By.xpath(InsertPath));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Insert));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Insert.click(); 
        WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.xpath(closePath));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(close));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        close.click();
        }
     }
```

**Edit:** I also used finding the element using Javascript executor in my code as follows:

```
        WebElement Insert = driver.findElement(By.xpath(InsertPath));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Insert);
```

Sadly, this method also failed to work in the IE browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to locate the elements by using the latest driver of the Internet Explorer and giving the following desired capabilities in my code to the IE browser.

```
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);   
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);*/
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```